# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification wrongly called from next class in stack

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard, pushviewcontroller

I detect when the keyboard will show with the below code. However, when I push to another screen using pushViewController and open the keyboard in that screen, keyboardWillShow is getting called! Is this really correct?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                           object:nil];
// register for keyboard notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this is correct behavior. 
Since the view that pushes the other view is still alive and the notifications are app wide.

You could remove the notification in the:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                                  object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                                  object:nil];
}
```

And if you want to set the observer then place you code from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                           object:nil];
    // register for keyboard notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                           object:nil];
}
```

Comment: +1 though you may want to mention how to remove observer for that notification.

Comment: Yes Praveen. Im just trying to work out where to put the following code - 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                                  object:nil];

Comment: something like - (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                                  object:nil]; 
    // unregister for keyboard notifications while not visible.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                                  object:nil]; 
}

Comment: viewDidUnload isn't being called when I push to a new screen. Which is correct I think.

Comment: I've added my post to show you how to correctly remove the observers.

Comment: @rckoenes, there is a small typo in the answer. in viewWillAppear: the call to super should be viewWillAppear ;)
+1 for the answer though. I was looking where to correctly put the registration for notification code because I was not sure if in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear, and same for Disappearing...